# Литрература по zendframework + dojo

Tags: книги, zend-framework

День добрый!
Не подскажете, есть ли русскоязычная литература zendframework + dojo?

Answer (score 1):

В бумажном виде ни разу не встречалось. А статьи в блогах иногда попадаются, например:

- [Zend_Dojo: первые шаги](http://habrahabr.ru/blogs/zend_framework/60472/)
- [Создание интерфейсов с помощью Dojo и Zend Framework](http://www.rismagi.ru/2010/05/dojo-plus-zend-framework/)

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличная книга от O'Reilly: **Dojo. Подробное руководство.**, автор Мэтью А. Рассел.